# Identify different shapes drawn using UIBezierPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I am able to draw shapes using the UIBezierPath object. Now I want to identify different shapes drawn using this eg. Rectangle , Square , Triangle , Circle etc. Then next thing I want to do is that user should be able to select a particular shape and should be able to move the whole shape to different location on the screen. The actual requirement is even more complex , but If I could make this much then I can work out on the rest.

Any suggestion or links or points on how do I start with this is welcome . I am thinking of writing a separate view to handle every shape but not getting how do I do that..

Thank You all in advance !!

Comment: I am also looking for same solution. Please do post your solution if you find it.

Comment: Are you able to identify shapes?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend David Gelphman’s *Programming with Quartz*.

In his chapter “Drawing with Paths” he has a section on “Path Construction Primitives” which provides a crossroads:

If you use `CGContextAddLineToPoint` your user could make straight lines defined by known Cartesian points. You would use basic math to deduce the geometric shapes defined by those points.

If you use `CGContextAddCurveToPoint` your user could make *curved* lines defined by known points, and I’m pretty sure that those lines would run *through* the points, so you could still use basic math to determine at least an approximation of the types of shapes formed.

But if you use `CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint`, the points define a framework *outside* of the drawn curve. You’d need more advanced math to determine the shapes formed by curves along tangents.

Gelphman also discusses “Path Utility Functions,” like getting a bounding box and checking whether a given point is inside the path.

As for moving the completed paths, I think you would use `CGContextTranslateCTM`.